# JavaMail unable to read XML attachments

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I've developed a Java Client application which I use to download my own email. I've found out that I'm unable to find some attachments within the email, in particular the XML file that I receive as receipt when I send an email to a certified company.
The code I use for downloading attachments:

```
private void getAttachment(Message message) throws Exception {

    Multipart multipart = (Multipart) message.getContent();

    for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
        BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);

        if (!Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(bodyPart.getDisposition())
                && StringUtils.isEmpty(bodyPart.getFileName())) {
            continue; // dealing with attachments only
        }
        InputStream is = bodyPart.getInputStream();
        File f = new File("tmp/" + bodyPart.getFileName());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
            fos.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        fos.close();

    }

}
```

My question is: is there any restriction in downloading XML attachments ? or should I rather hook for different methods of the Message class ? Thanks

Comment: Do you manage to get other attachement types? What happens if you get rid of the `if` part ?

Comment: Yes I manage to read other attachments. By removing the if part the body of the mail will be downloaded as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "ATTACHMENT" disposition and the filename are only recommendations, not requirements.  Some messages will have "attachments" without setting these.  In most cases you should consider any body part after the first in a multipart/mixed message to be an attachment.  See the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#hasattach) for more information.